# ol3 custom build missing export for map.getSize

Tags: openlayers-3, custom-build

I'm trying to make a custom build of ol3.  I can get everything to work with:

```
{"exports":["*"], ...}
```

but not with an export list.  it appears it should be under ol.Map, but I have that.  Any reason why my custom build throws an exception for getSize missing with this command:

```
view.fit(extent, map.getSize());
```

Here is my custom build json:

```
{
  "exports": [
    "ol.Feature",
    "ol.Feature#*",
    "ol.geom.Point",
    "ol.geom.Point#*",
    "ol.layer.Tile",
    "ol.layer.Tile#*",
    "ol.layer.Vector",
    "ol.layer.Vector#*",
    "ol.Map",
    "ol.proj.transform",
    "ol.source.OSM",
    "ol.source.OSM#*",
    "ol.source.Vector",
    "ol.source.Vector#*",
    "ol.style.Icon",
    "ol.style.Icon#*",
    "ol.style.Style",
    "ol.style.Style#*",
    "ol.View",
    "ol.View#*",
    "ol.extent.boundingExtent"
    ],
  "compile": {
    "externs": [
      "externs/bingmaps.js",
      "externs/geojson.js",
      "externs/oli.js",
      "externs/olx.js",
      "externs/proj4js.js",
      "externs/tilejson.js",
      "externs/topojson.js"
    ],
    "define": [
      "goog.dom.ASSUME_STANDARDS_MODE=true",
      "goog.DEBUG=false"
    ],
    "compilation_level": "ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS",

    "output_wrapper": "(function(){%output%})();",
    "use_types_for_optimization": true,
    "manage_closure_dependencies": true
  }
}
```

Comment: there have been changes with the latest versions of ol `view.fit(extent, map.getSize());` now accepts a geometry and not extent. Though, it should work for the extent as well but just in case try it like `view.fit(geometry, map.getSize());` check it here  http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.View.html

Comment: I don't understand this. This problem has to be with my custom build. It works perfectly when I use the full ("*") export list but fails on the minimal export list. Just trying to cut down on the size for mobile.

Comment: Tried adding ol.geom.SimpleGeometry since fit does take a geometry (as well as an extent) but that doesn't matter. The problem is ol.Map missing the getSize function. Here is my map definition if that helps. var map = new ol.Map({ view: view, layers: mapLayers, target: 'SitesMap', renderer: 'canvas' });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't add a comment due to lack of reputation, so I'm not sure if this is a correct answer or not.

Try:

```
"ol.Map#*"
```

Or:

```
"ol.Map#getSize"
```

I think that this would include the `ol.Map` functions.

Comment: You are correct, any method you want, you have to include it, `"ol.Map#getSize"`, or use `*`.

Comment: I swear I tried the #* at one point... Thanks for the help.  By the way, if any ol3 people see this, when I search I can't find any information on the syntax you show here.  I've read thru the first page of google entries after searching "ol3 custom build".  I see the syntax on one entry but no mention of what the syntax means.